# Datatype in SQL Server for "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff"

Tags: sql-server

I have to save this `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff` datetime format in MS `SQL` DB as datetime 
so what should be the `datatype` for it ?

Comment: Well `DATETIME`/`DATETIME2` are the types for Date & Time.

Comment: You should pick types *designed* for storing datetime data. Note, carefully, in almost all languages, that type will not have a *format*. A format is an artefact of converting to or from *strings*. When you have it in the right datatype, it's frequently just a count since some particular epoch date. For instance, in SQL Server, `datetime2` counts the number of 100ns intervals since midnight at the start of 01/01/0001

Comment: [This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160709/sql-datetime20-vs-datetime22) lists the proper data type per your requirements.

Comment: Using the TIMESTAMP format, you can save this "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff" format

Answer (score 1):

you can use  `datetime` data type as you need 6digit then use

```
datetime2

datetime2 time range 00:00:00 through 23:59:59.9999999  


SELECT  convert(DATETIME2, getdate()) 
its output
2018-07-25 03:28:37.7300000
```

you can use `datetime2(6)` according to Dan Guzman comments
  The default datetime2 precision is datetime2(7)

Comment: I need to save 6 fractional second after second (after ss) , actually??

Comment: [`datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) has contained the following notice for *quite some time*: "Use the `time`, `date`, `datetime2` and `datetimeoffset` data types for new work. These types align with the SQL Standard." Why give an answer that provides outdated advice?

Comment: yes i got as his need more so it would be  datetime2

Comment: @Ayush, if you want exactly 6 fractional second precision, you can use `datetime2(6)`. The default  `datetime2` precision is `datetime2(7)`.